# Error deploying node project on vercel after updating to Node.js v18

Tags: typescript, vercel

I have a very simple typescript API that I use for a twitch stream that I created after reading an online getting started tutorial. My viewers have been using this CLI in chat for about 2 years now without problems but recently after making an update the vercel deployment failed because I needed to update to Node.js v18. After doing that in the project settings on vercel, I now get these errors when it tries to build/deploy. I'm sure I just need to do something simple like update my local node installation using npm but everything I've tried so far has failed.

```
[10:40:58.919] Running build in Washington, D.C., USA (East) – iad1
[10:40:58.985] Cloning bitbucket.org/JonWiesman/twitchbot (Branch: master, Commit: 2222239)
[10:41:00.430] Cloning completed: 1.445s
[10:41:00.571] Skipping build cache since Node.js version changed from "16.x" to "18.x"
[10:41:01.133] Running "vercel build"
[10:41:01.644] Vercel CLI 30.2.3
[10:41:01.893] Installing dependencies...
[10:41:02.687] npm WARN old lockfile 
[10:41:02.687] npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
[10:41:02.688] npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.
[10:41:02.688] npm WARN old lockfile 
[10:41:02.688] npm WARN old lockfile This is a one-time fix-up, please be patient...
[10:41:02.688] npm WARN old lockfile 
[10:41:10.357] npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
[10:41:10.708] npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
[10:41:10.835] npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
[10:41:10.917] npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.0: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
[10:41:11.312] npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
[10:41:12.466] npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
[10:41:28.905] 
[10:41:28.905] added 651 packages in 27s
[10:41:28.905] 
[10:41:28.905] 30 packages are looking for funding
[10:41:28.906]   run `npm fund` for details
[10:41:28.933] Detected Next.js version: 10.0.3
[10:41:28.940] Detected `package-lock.json` generated by npm 7+...
[10:41:28.940] Running "npm run build"
[10:41:29.238] 
[10:41:29.238] > with-typescript@1.0.0 build
[10:41:29.239] > next build
[10:41:29.239] 
[10:41:29.882] Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
[10:41:29.882] npx browserslist@latest --update-db
[10:41:29.930] node:internal/errors:490
[10:41:29.931]     ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
[10:41:29.931]     ^
[10:41:29.931] 
[10:41:29.931] Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './lib/parser' is not defined by "exports" in /vercel/path0/underbot/node_modules/postcss/package.json
[10:41:29.931]     at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
[10:41:29.931]     at exportsNotFound (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:361:10)
[10:41:29.931]     at packageExportsResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:697:9)
[10:41:29.931]     at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:565:36)
[10:41:29.931]     at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:634:31)
[10:41:29.932]     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:27)
[10:41:29.932]     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
[10:41:29.932]     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
[10:41:29.932]     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
[10:41:29.932]     at 552 (/vercel/path0/underbot/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-scss/scss-syntax.js:1:11590) {
[10:41:29.932]   code: 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED'
[10:41:29.933] }
[10:41:29.933] 
[10:41:29.933] Node.js v18.15.0
[10:41:29.955] Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
[10:41:30.431] BUILD_UTILS_SPAWN_1: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

I've tried

npm update

but it says I don't have a package.json (I have a package_lock.json?) so I'm not sure if my installation is just fubar'd or what.

Comment: `package.json` is necessary for `npm` to update your dependencies. The `package-lock.json` is auto generated on install, and can be used to ensure dependencies are exactly the same between multiple installations, but it is not a substitute for `package.json`. If `npm` is telling you it doesn't see one, you're either running the command in the wrong directory, the file was deleted, or you've never had one and just been using someone else's lockfile. Let me know what the case is.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know what the case is. There is a package.json in one of the subfolders of my repo so I ran npm update node in there and then tried to push that but it said there were huge files above 10MB so I'm pretty sure I did something wrong and now it's probably really screwed up.